# Why do a lot of new low cost IoT modules use a MIPS 24K processor rather than ARM?

Tags: microcontroller, arm, mips, soc

it seems like a lot of new low cost (< $20) IoT modules that pair a microcontroller with 802.11 networking rely on the MIPS 24K processor. Based on my experience this is a relatively obscure choice, as opposed to an ARM microcontroller. Is there a reason why the MIPS processor is more appropriate for this application than say an STM32 (ARM Cortex M3)?

Why is this?

Examples of MIPS-based IoT modules:

- The [Omega](http://hackerboards.com/tiny-stackable-linux-based-iot-module-hits-kickstarter/), contains the [Atheros AR9331](https://www.openhacks.com/uploadsproductos/ar9331_datasheet.pdf)
- The [Omega 2](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/onion/omega2-5-iot-computer-with-wi-fi-powered-by-linux), contains the [MediaTek MT7688](http://www.mediatek.com/en/products/connectivity/wifi/home-network/wifi-ap/mt7688ka/)
- The [Black Swift](http://hackerboards.com/tiny-low-cost-wifi-ready-iot-sbc-runs-openwrt-linux/), also contains the MT7688

I could imagine a reason to be cost, ease of electrical integration, or driver support.

Comment: You would have to ask the individuals at those companies why.  Could have been personal choice, price, they took a vote in a meeting one day, somebody knows somebody, any number of reasons that we will never know outside the company.  Why didnt they use an ARC instead of an ARM or any other instruction set?

Comment: MIPS is not "relatively obscure", it is very common in the embedded world.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These basically inherit from the now very long history of MIPS-based, external-RAM wifi routers running Embedded Linux or various other full-featured embedded operating systems.  Effectively the resulting products are routers that no longer route, and have assorted gadgetry in place of blinkenlights on their GPIOs.

As for why those are MIPS, because people started building them that way before the large embedded ARM parts were as dominant as they have become in the past decade.  Some of the licensing deals for the cores may well now be fairly entrenched.

Note that there is little comparison to a "small" ARM part like a Cortex M3, which is designed to run from internal flash with limited storage in internal static RAM (there are Cortex M3's with external memory buses, but it's not their common strength).  There are of course IoT solutions with a Cortex M3 or M4 at their heart (WICED, etc) but typically for more constrained needs.  And they aren't necessarily that much cheaper.

The ARM parts that would be more directly comparable are the trailing-edge tablet, phone, and set-top box chips - but these are less likely to have wifi tightly integrated.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! What do you mean when you say "there are IoT solutions with a Cortex ... typically for mor constrained needs", a $5 product like the Omega 2 seems pretty "constrained"?

Comment: Price constrained, but maybe not constrained in intended functionality.  Essentially, you've demonstrated that the more *functionally constrained* Cortex-M3 type devices aren't necessarily cheaper.

Answer (score 2):

The RF chipset and the microprocessor aren't separate in those IoT modules, they are together in a single SoC/SoM package.

Many of the SoC designs are probably quite old (that Atheros chip, is at least 6 years old, and is probably an evolution of an even older design), so the choice of MIPS over ARM likely made more sense back then.

This is somewhat common with RF components, because the design and certification process for them is so expensive, nobody wants to make unnecessary changes.